# How to respond to 'Would you like to come with us?'

Tags: responses

- Would you like to come with us?
- Oh, sure. I'd love to.

It is from our OXFORD student book. So my question is

Can students just answer 'I'd love to.' , 'Sure.', 'OK.' or 'That sounds great!'? without 'Yes or No'?

Comment: Since it's from an Oxford book, why do you think "yes" or "no" must be used as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can answer it that way. The "yes" would be understood. You can also include the "yes" : "Yes, I'd love to."

"I'd love to..." and "That sounds great..." could also mean a refusal, if followed by "but" and a reason not to go.